# How to configure vertical spacing for ASP .Net treeview with checkbox

Tags: asp.net, treeview, checkbox, skinning

The [display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IelPN.png) is awful; there are some spaces between lines.

I'm using a `asp:treeview` in my web page. The appearance is configured with skin.The `TreeViewSkin` is written into `SkinFile.skin` available under `App_Themes`:

```
<asp:TreeView SkinID="TreeViewSkin" runat="server" ShowLines="true" ShowCheckBoxes="All" Style="margin-top:10px;">
  <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" />
  <NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" HorizontalPadding="5px" NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
  <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
  <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

For information the data binding is done by `BuildTreeview` method:

```
public static void BuildTreeView<T>(this IEnumerable<HierarchyNode<T>> hierarchy, TreeView treeView, string idName, string libName) where T : class
{
    TreeNode treeNode = null;
    var treeview = typeof(T);
    foreach (var obj in hierarchy)
    {
        var nameProperty = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Entity");
        if (nameProperty == null) continue;
        var value = (T)nameProperty.GetValue(obj, null);
        var property = treeview.GetProperty(idName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var curElementIdValue = Convert.ToInt32(property.GetValue(value, null));

        var labelProperty = treeview.GetProperty(libName, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var labelValue = (string)labelProperty.GetValue(value, null);

        if (value != null)  treeNode = new TreeNode() {Text = labelValue, Value = curElementIdValue.ToString()};

        var childNodes = obj.GetType().GetProperty("ChildNodes");
        if (childNodes != null) {
            var propValue = childNodes.GetValue(obj, null);
            BuildTreeNode<T>(propValue as IEnumerable, treeNode, idName, libName);
        }
        if (treeNode != null) treeView.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
    }
}
```

I'm not the code's owner; I admit that the code of the method is somewhat obscure...
Is it wrong to show checkbox? I can reproduce partially with Chrome with this [sample](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/samples/ctrlref/navigation/TreeView/treeview04_lines_vb.aspx) but not in IE7. I'm disappointed ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround on [blogs.msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloc/archive/2007/05/23/broken-line-in-asp-net-2-0-treeview-in-ie-7.aspx)

```
The {DIV} tag generated height is only 1px instead of 20px.
```